# How to secure a verification system on iPads with QR Codes

Tags: ios, security, encryption, qr-code

I have created an iPad application that uses QR Codes for verification. In order to "verify" the document a person must scan an official QR Code. I am worried about the people taking a picture of the QR code and then creating other copies of it. Is there anyway to secure this process? Maybe encrypt the text in the QR Codes? Except that still wouldnt do anything if the person was to create a new one. Any ideas?

More clarification: It is an app that allows students to create hallpasses digitally which are then digitally "signed" or verified by the teacher by scanning a QR Code on the teachers ID. Hopefully the students would be unable to capture the QR Code on the ID but I am trying to add an extra layer of security in case this was to happen. Is this possible?

Comment: If you are looking for security advice you will need to disclose more about the use case. It is like store coupons that you do not walt duplicated? It is QR that is attached to a document like a sticker? How is it used and what is it trying to prevent. Also what is the value of the document it is to protect--in dollars.

Comment: I updated the original question'

Comment: There is nothing you can do to the data in the QR code itself that will prevent copying. You need to attack the problem through validation and/or expiration of the data. If a pass is only valid for, say, 15 minutes the you could encode the time (and use some sort of encryption so that it wasn't trivial to forge a new code) or if you have some server back end to issue and validate the codes then you can just use a UUID in the QR code with the server validating the code. Once a code expires it can't be used again and you can't predict a valid UUID in order to forge a pass

Comment: Rereading your question I see now it is the teacher's id that could be copied. Perhaps you could require the teacher to enter a PIN along with the scan of their ID.

Comment: The solution is simple and low-tech (sorry). Issue the pass. If a student is caught using a forged pass (as determined by talking to the issuer) punish the student. One could add more info to restrict the areas and times the pass is valid for. In my case they managed to expel me several times all without any hi-tech. ;-)